# Is sexist humor occurring in the Skeptics SE community?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've come across comments like [this in a question about hymens and girls' virginity:](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4187/can-you-reliably-detect-if-a-girl-is-a-virgin)

> If a girl puts out, you can be
>   reasonably sure of her virginity.

and [this one in a question about rape:](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/is-a-woman-who-dresses-sexually-suggestively-more-likely-to-get-raped)

> [***6 comment upvotes***] Let's reason ab
>   absurdo. A woman that doesn't dress at
>   all is not ... wait ...

Should comments like this be flagged as offensive, or am I imagining sexism when there's none there? And should I be worried that the latter comment got 6 upvotes?

Comment: These two comments are offensive. I agree. They should be flagged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've removed the two comments. Personally, I don't see the second one has sexist, but other people have. Since it's just a silly comment anyhow, I prefer to err on the side of caution and just delete the comment. I might just not be seeing something that other people do see.

I'll jump on this opportunity to remember people to **please use your flags**. Flags will alert us of problematic comments, and the more of them on a comment the better.

Comment: We really need to be very careful that this site avoids comments such as those listed above IMHO.

Comment: note also that comment flagging has changed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93821/what-are-valid-reasons-for-flagging-comments